# Committing local files to a remote git repository

Tags: github, terminal, command-line, command, repository

I'm trying to commit some files that I've created on a local github repository of mine, to the remote repository. I tried to do use the "git commit" command, but after doing this, I get a message saying "Please use a feature branch". However, I don't currently have any other branches on this repository. I have attached an image of my issue to this post. [image: 'git commit' error]

I also tried to use "git push", but this did not work either. I got an error that says that it "Failed to push some refs" to the repository.[image: 'git push' error]

Does anyone know what I need to do in order to successfully commit the data in my local repository into my remote one? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the repo your personal ? Then check in your GitHub account in repo what is the allowed way to push code.
If the repo belongs to someone else, the settings are set to use feature branch.
In that case :

1. Checkout from the main branch git checkout -b yourname/branch_name
2. Add your code in the new checkout branch
3. Commit and push
4. Go to the remote repository and create a pull request from your newly created branch yourname/branch-name to the main branch and submit the pull request.

Comment: This repo is for a college class, but is owned by me, on my account. However, I looked through some of the requirements for the repo, and this is one of the requirements it has: "Create and checkout branch: branch name -- assignment/<#> -- each branch must refer to an issue on GitHub; where # is actual issue number GitHub provides: 1 e.g..". So, I'm thinking I need to keep the feature branch settings. I tried the steps you gave, and whenever I try 'git checkout' on a branch other than main, it creates a new branch with that name. So, I tried 'git branch feature'.

Comment: After navigating into the 'feature' branch, I tried to readd the files I'm wishing to commit to the remote repository, and retried 'git commit' inside this new branch. I got the following: "Running pre-commit hook on branch: feature
ERROR on Commit. Branch name must adhere to this contract: ^(lab|project|assignment|homework|issue|dev|feature|bugfix|improvement|library|prerelease|release|hotfix)\/[a-z0-9._-]+$. Rename your branch to a valid name and try again.
git branch -m <branch/sub-branch>"

Comment: So, what kind of name do I need to give the branch in order to get it to "adhere to" the above contract??

Answer (score 0):

Try `git push -u origin master` and not `git push`.

And talking about the feature branch thing, if you are a beginner you can ignore this. It isn't anything to worry about.

However, if you are still curious then let me tell you that it comes under good engineering practice to deploy the code first in your development branch/Feature branch and then merge it with the main branch to avoid any future issues. You can read more about it and try to teach other good engineering principles while making personal projects as well that will help you in future.